# Sql DataFrame - Operation

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am stuck with a situation where i need to perform division on output from two sql Data Frame . Any Suggestion How it can be done ?

```
scala> val TotalDie = sqlc.sql("select COUNT(DISTINCT XY) from Data")
TotalDie: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: bigint]

scala> TotalDie.show()
+---+
|_c0|
+---+
|887|
+---+

scala> val PassDie = sqlc.sql("select COUNT(DISTINCT XY) from Data where Sbin = '1'")
PassDie: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: bigint]

scala> PassDie.show()
+---+
|_c0|
+---+
|413|
+---+
```

I need to perform to calculate the Yield which refer to (PassDie/TotalDie)*100, 
I am new to spark-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of multiple values (ie multiple rows): do you have a column (or key or id) to join the two dataframes (or tables) on ?

In case of always a single value (ie single row): something along the lines of: 100* PassDie.collect() / TotalDie.collect()

**UPDATE**
The exact syntax in case of 1 value: 

`100.0 * passdie.collect()(0).getInt(0) / totaldie.collect()(0).getInt(0)
res25: Double = 46.56144306651635`

Comment: Hi willem , it only have one row at any time , I tried your solution but it throws the error as shown below

scala> val Yield = PassDie.collect() / TotalDie.collect()
<console>:45: error: value / is not a member of Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
         val Yield = PassDie.collect() / TotalDie.collect()
                                       ^

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with just SparkSQL, too.

Here's what i'd do to solve it that way:

```
>>> rdd1 = sc.parallelize([("a",1.12),("a",2.22)])
>>> rdd2 = sc.parallelize([("b",9.12),("b",12.22)])
>>> r1df = rdd1.toDF()
>>> r2df = rdd2.toDF()
>>> r1df.registerTempTable('r1')
>>> r2df.registerTempTable('r2')
>>> r3df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM r1 UNION SELECT * FROM r2").show()
>>> r3df.registerTempTable('r3')
>>> sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM r3") -------> do your aggregation / math here.
```

Now from here, in theory, you can do basic grouping and arithmetic just using SQL queries, since you've got this grand table of data. I realize in my example code, I didn't really declare a good schema with column names, and that makes this example not really work, but you have a schema, so you get the idea.